# Android - how to post a Tweet to Twitter directly (without an implicit intent or other application)?

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

Good afternoon everybody.  I'm following this tutorial:

http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/11/twitter-login-android-studio-example.html

which has this associated GitHub project:

https://github.com/androidwarriors/TwitterLoginUsingFabric

Everything seems to be working, when I get to the lines:

```
String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(MainActivity.this).text("test tweet 789");
builder.show();
getUserData();
```

I am able to see the Toast confirming successful login and then apparently an implicit intent is started, the phone asks which browser I would prefer to use, then opens that browser with "test tweet 789" already entered and a button to send the tweet.

The concern is, I would like to directly send the tweet from my app, rather than bringing up a browser as a separate app to do so.  Is there a way to do this?  Seems like an easy question and it's probably only another line of code or two but I could not find a directly applicable example, please advise.  Sorry if I'm missing something easy here.

For the record here is my entire onCreate method, mostly directly from the tutorial linked above.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_username);

    loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // The TwitterSession is also available through:
            // Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession()

            Log.d("Twitter ", "Login sucessfull");
            session = result.data;

            String username = session.getUserName();
            userid = session.getUserId();

            textView.setText("Hi " + username);
            TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
            String token = authToken.token;
            String secret = authToken.secret;
            // TODO: Remove toast and use the TwitterSession's userID
            // with your app's user model
            String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(MainActivity.this).text("test tweet 789");
            builder.show();
            getUserData();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silently posting tweets doesn't seem to be part of Fabric's SDK. You may want to look at [their REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update).